# Flask wtforms DecimalField not displaying in HTML

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

My TextField forms are displaying fine in the html page, but not the DecimalFields. The DecimalFields don't display at all.

My forms.py:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, validators, IntegerField, DateField, BooleanField, DecimalField

class EnterPart(Form):
    Description = TextField(label='label', description="description", validators=[validators.required()])
    VendorCost = DecimalField(label='label',description="cost")
```

My application.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
def index():
    form = EnterPart(request.form) 
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

My index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% import 'macros.html' as macros %} 
{% block content %}
{{ form.hidden_tag() }} 
{{ macros.render_field(form.Description, placeholder='Description', type='dbSerial', label_visible=false) }}
    {{ macros.render_field(form.VendorCost, placeholder='Category', type='dbSerial', label_visible=false) }}
    {% endblock %}
```

I've been building from the tutorial here:
http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does `macros.render_field` do?

Comment: It's supposed to render the field for bootstrap standards. But you're right, that's where the issue is coming from. Using the code from the tutorial, macros.html doesn't have an option for DecimalField, which is why it's not being rendered at all.

Answer (score 0):

Macros.html didn't have an option for dealing with DecimalField. By adding a rendering option for DecimalField, it now displays correctly.

I changed a block in macros.html from:

```
<div class="form-group {% if field.errors %}has-error{% endif %} {{ kwargs.pop('class_', '') }}">
    {% if (field.type != 'HiddenField' or field.type !='CSRFTokenField') and label_visible %}
        <label for="{{ field.id }}" class="control-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
    {% endif %}
    {% if field.type == 'TextField' %}
        {{ field(class_='form-control', **kwargs) }}
    {% endif %}
    {% if field.errors %}
        {% for e in field.errors %}
            <p class="help-block">{{ e }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

to:

```
<div class="form-group {% if field.errors %}has-error{% endif %} {{ kwargs.pop('class_', '') }}">
    {% if (field.type != 'HiddenField' or field.type !='CSRFTokenField') and label_visible %}
        <label for="{{ field.id }}" class="control-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
    {% endif %}
    {% if field.type == 'TextField' %}
        {{ field(class_='form-control', **kwargs) }}
    {% endif %}
    {% if field.type == 'DecimalField' %}
        {{ field(class_='form-control', **kwargs) }}
    {% endif %}
    {% if field.errors %}
        {% for e in field.errors %}
            <p class="help-block">{{ e }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```